# FusedLocationProviderClient crashes on Google Play services version 12.0.0 update

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-client

So [Google release](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) the following warning:

> Warning: **Please continue using the FusedLocationProviderApi** class and
>   don't migrate to the FusedLocationProviderClient class **until Google
>   Play services version 12.0.0 is available**, which is expected to ship
>   in early 2018. **Using the FusedLocationProviderClient before version
>   12.0.0 causes the client app to crash when Google Play services is updated on the device**. We apologize for any inconvenience this may
>   have caused.

*(emphasis mine)*

I find the language a bit ambigous. If I decide to use the new `FusedLocationProviderClient`, will the app crash **ONLY** once, or will it crash **FOREVER**, requiring the user to reinstall the app? Also, will it crash **ONLY** if the app is running while the update is in place, or after the updated happens, no matter the app state at the time?

I fint the **FOREVER** case scenario hard to believe, but I rather check before jumping into conclusions, since I don't care much about one little crash.

---

**EDIT:**

This issue is fixed apparently, it was addressed on [Google Play Services version 11.6.0 update](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases):

> Fixed FusedLocationProviderClientissue that occasionally caused crashes when Google Play services updated.

Just be aware there's still a known issue on this version:

> **Known Issues with version 11.6.0**
>
> GoogleApi instances created with a Context in apps with targetSdkVersion 26 won't automatically prompt users to update Google Play services. Consider using GoogleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment() under these conditions instead.

Comment: As I understand it, the client app, if running, will crash everytime Google Play services package is updated, until it gets updated to v12.x.x.

Comment: @NirajSanghani The whole point of Google Play services (GMS) is that its use is SDK level agnostic. You can install any version of GMS package on any device. Yes, once Android 8.1 starts rolling out, GMS 12 will be released, but *to all devices* not just Android 8.1. Once the GMS *package* v12 is installed on a device, you can still use all previous versions of the GMS *API library* that's bundled with your app. Just in this case `FusedLocationProviderClient` will magically stop crashing.

Comment: @EugenPechanec and that's another way to read it....maybe I should add to the list

Comment: I don't see this warning, following your link.

Comment: They removed the message, it's apparently fixed. I will update the question with the links for the fixed version.